# Is there any way to turn off the synchronizing of save games?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6, ubisoft-connect

When Might & Magic: Heroes VI is closed, Ubisoft's Uplay service pops up a window that says "Synchronizing Save Games", which takes a very long time to complete and often fails without any obvious reason.  For some time I just accepted the delay as an annoying penalty for legally obtaining my copy of the game.

For the past two nights, the synchronizing has failed every time it occurs, and it is also attempting (and failing) to synchronize whenever I start the game, adding to the delay and my frustration.  However, even with the synchronizing failing, I am still able to access my campaign save games and play through them, so it appears that I am connecting to the service properly.

Since the synchronizing does not appear to be working, nor does it appear to be providing me with any benefit, is there some way to turn it off and still play online?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn off the syncronization in the UPlay settings.

Comment: There are settings in UPlay?  I did not know that.